# Can i somehow set update time for FixedUpdate?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm just curious if can i have more control over that function.

Comment: Can you give us a little context about what you want to do with it?

Comment: You can change the time step of this method (the whole physics system). https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please remember to search the documentation first.

- In the Unity Editor, you can control the period of FixedUpdate
  ticks using the [Time Manager](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TimeManager.html) (Edit > Project Settings > Time)
- In scripts, you can set this period via [Time.fixedDeltaTime](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-fixedDeltaTime.html)